# Adding a Filter to a Stimulsoft report using Web Designer

Tags: report, stimulsoft

I am developing some reports using Stimulsoft web report designer. I need to add some data filters to those reports. Stimulsoft reports has data filters in built to it and they are shown when the reports are rendered. But I couldn't find a way to configure those data filters. Does anybody knows a way to do this?

I found some Interesting data filters on Stimulsoft demo site. I am looking to use this in my reports. http://web.stimulsoft.com/?reportname=ParametersSelectingCountry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the Filter property of the Band. You could use there any expression.

Comment: Hi HighAley, I can add filters using property band. But I want to allow the user to select values from filter. Is there a way to load values to the filter criteria selector.

Comment: You can set the Interaction - Sorting Column property to allow users to sort data.

Comment: Look at the next Demo report http://web.stimulsoft.com/?reportname=DrillDownSorting

Comment: Hi HighAley, Thanks for your reply. Actually what I am looking for is to have a filter like in this report.                     http://web.stimulsoft.com/?reportname=ParametersSelectingCountry. Is this filter configured outside the report? Because I couldn't find any configuration in the report designer. How can I set the data source for the filter?

Comment: Look at the SelectedCountry variable in the Dictionary. You can see how to create such report on the next video http://www.stimulsoft.com/en/videos?tags=web,parameters&id=68

Comment: Hi HighAley, The video is really helpful. I think this solves my problem.